# iOS - How To Know If I Need A Routing App Coverage File

Tags: ios, routes, mapkit, app-store-connect

I tried to submit an app to the Apple App Store on iTunes Connect and I got this error message:

*"To configure this app as an iOS routing app, upload a routing app coverage file on the app's Version page in My Apps on iTunes Connect."*

My app uses MapKit to show the locations of various monuments in the user's city, and to provide directions on how to get to them. I Googled this error and interestingly most people that have answered it seem to be saying that the file is actually not needed, but I'm not sure if that applies to the features my app offers.

How do I know if I actually need a routing coverage file? And if I do need one, can I make it cover the whole globe (i.e. the app should work anywhere in the world)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer was to turn off MapKit altogether, eg. to uncheck it in the project capabilities tab. MapKit only needs to be turned on for "routing", which is a term I misunderstood. Routing means that other apps, such as Apple/Google maps, can use your app to display directions. I only wanted to show directions within my app, so turning on MapKit was unnecessary.